# Spring java config bean definition overriding

Tags: spring-java-config

In my Spring application, I have a main `@Configuration` class named, let's say, `ConfigApplication`. I also have some profile-based configurations classes, `ConfigDev` and `ConfigProd`. The situation is resumed as following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("fr.gf.predication.*")
@Import(value = ConfigSecurity.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:configuration/default.properties")
public class ConfigApplication {

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(loadHibernateConfiguration());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

If I choose to move the `dataSource` bean definition to have a specific configuration (with and without connection pool for example) between my environments, I will have to duplicate all other beans definition (`entityManagerFactory`, `transactionManager`) because they need the dataSource bean.

I tried to override this bean definition in my `ConfigProd` class but it seems to be ignored by Spring until it already has loaded the bean in the main config class...
Is there a way to achieve this environment-specific configuration? Or should I re-think the design of these classes?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. I have just added the annotation `@Import(ConfigApplication.class)` in my `ConfigProd` class. With this, the dataSource bean definition is overwritten as expected.